# If a sequence of random variables converges in probability to $0$, will the sequence still converge to $0$ when multiplied by $\sqrt n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, asymptotics, statistical-inference

Assume we have a sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2...$ such that the sequence converges to $0$ in probability. Under what general conditions will the sequence still converge in probability to $0$ when multiplied by $\sqrt n $?

Comment: Check Lyapunov's condition.  
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LyapunovCondition.html

Comment: Putting aside the fact that these are random variables, is there a simple condition on a sequence of real numbers $(x_n) \rightarrow 0$ to ensure that $(\sqrt{n}x_n) \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: I think Lyapunov's condition deals with convergence in distribution to a normal RV not convergence in probability to a constant. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @user6247850 I can think of $sqrt n =o(\frac{1}{X_n})$ as a necessary but vague condition

Comment: Yes, you are right. A sufficient condition for the modified sequence $\sqrt(n)X_n$ to converge in probability to $0$ is that the rate at which $X_n$ converges to $0$ is faster than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: @UniformIntegrability Yeah, but that's essentially just the definition of $o(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$.  I think that's basically all you can do for these sorts of things: this doesn't follow from any simple property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $X_1, X_2, ...$ converging in probability to $0$ means that the following holds:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n - 0| > \varepsilon) = 0.
\end{align}
To check wether the sequence $\sqrt{n} X_1, \sqrt{n} X_2, ...$ converges in probability to $0$ you would have to check if the following holds:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|\sqrt{n} X_n - 0| > \varepsilon) = 0.
\end{align}
Now observe that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|\sqrt{n} X_n - 0| > \varepsilon) =&
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(\sqrt{n} |X_n| > \varepsilon)
\\
=& \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n| > \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n}})
\end{align}
Using Markovs inequality we can find an upper bound as
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n| > \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n}}) \leq 
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n} E(|X_n|)}{\varepsilon}
\end{align}
So one general condition would be that the expectation of the sequence $|X_1|,|X_2|,...$ (mind the absolute value!) converges faster to zero than $\frac{1}{n}$. Note: You could also use a quadratic function in Markovs inequality and obtain a condition for the second moment.
Another possibility is to use that convergence in $d$ and convergence in $p$ coincide if the sequence converges to a constant. So if you have more knowledge about the cdf and are able to show that
\begin{align}
F_{\sqrt{n}X_n}(t) = P(\sqrt{n}X_n \leq t) = P(X_n \leq \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}) \rightarrow
\begin{cases}
0 & t < 0
\\
1 & t \geq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
holds, you can also go this way.